# XSS - Does blacklisting of following characters take good enough care of XSS?

Tags: security, xss

I am blacklisting following characters for a variable which becomes part of the URL.

Please suggest if I am missing any or should exclude any.

```
"~!@#$%^*()+{}[]|<>\"\\:;,"
```

Comment: Blacklisting characters is never a good idea.  You should properly escape all concatenated strings.

Comment: It does not - only way how to prevent XSS is to properly encode ALL html outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it does not.

Also, *never* try to do security through blacklists. Use whitelists.

And never try to filter for XSS. Encode your output for the format you're writing to. For HTML (body and quoted attributes) then use something like php's [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Comment: Actually, I am having old and basic web app running C server pages (.CSPs).  So it is tough to call any other routines.

Comment: On getting any of this characters, I straight away return logout CSP file so the user gets logged out. In this scenario, it will be okay right?